# Servers to upload images

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I have 2 servers, one of them has the application for upload images and the folder that save the images is in the other server
So, how can i do that?? (connect the application with the folder in the other server)

Comment: What is the specific problem that you've faced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload your images with php, a solution is to upload via ftp the image to your second server (with folders to save images) from the first server.

You need :

```
private function ftpConnnect($ftp_server, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass)
{
    // set up basic connection 
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);        
    if(ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass))
    {
        echo "Logged In\n"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not Logged In\n";
    }
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    return $conn_id;
}

private function uploadOnServer($path, $saved_to, $ftp, $ftp_server_path)
{
    // upload a file 
    if (ftp_put($ftp, $ftp_server_path.$saved_to, $path, FTP_BINARY)) { 
        echo "successfully uploaded $ftp_server_path$saved_to\n"; 
    } else { 
        echo "There was a problem while uploading $ftp_server_path$saved_to\n"; 
    }  
}
```

Then call once :

```
$ftp = $this->ftpConnnect($serv, $user, $pass);
```

for each images

```
if($this->uploadOnServer($path, $saved_to, $ftp, $ftp_server_path))
    unlink($path);
```

And at the end :

```
ftp_close($ftp);
```